# Returning from if statement within a forEach within a function

Tags: javascript, object, return, return-value

I have written a small function which iterates over a multi-dimensional object and should return the result, if a match is found between two variables.

Here is my function in full:

```
function getData(config) {
  var code = "GB";

  return Object.keys(config).forEach(function(country) {
    if( Object.keys(config[country]).toString() === code ) {
      return config[country][code]; // { data: "my correct matching data" }
    }
  });
}
```

Testing at the point of the deepest `return`, I can see that `config[country][code]` outputs the result I expect. Great! A match was found between `config[country]` and `code` so I want to return it.

However the function as a whole returns `undefined`, but even setting the less deep `return` to store the result as a variable, and checking the value of that, I also get `undefined`. It seems though the match was found it is not returning correctly, see adjusted function below:

```
function getData(config) {
  var code = "GB";

  var result = Object.keys(config).forEach(function(country) {
    if( Object.keys(config[country]).toString() === code ) {
      return config[country][code]; // { data: "my correct matching data" }
    }
  });

  return result; // undefined
}
```

Any ideas why the result is not returning fully? I'm guessing I'm missing a return somewhere.

Comment: `forEach` always returns `undefined`.

Comment: You should use `find` instead of `forEach`. It's better suited to your use case.

Comment: `Array.prototype.forEach` returns `undefined`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach and `Object.keys` returns an `Array`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys